# Nette Framework - Route everything to one presenter

Tags: php, nette

I'm using Angular 2 in cooperation with Nette framework and I would like to let my Angular 2 **to do all the routing instead of Nette**.

Now when I use Angular 2 routing. I get an **Unexisting route exception** from Nette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To route **everything to one specific presenter**, simply add a new route into your RouteFactory (commonly in */app/RouterFactory.php*).

```
$router[] = new Route('/<param .+>', 'Homepage:default');
```

PS: You don't need to use `:default` action in linking. `Homepage` will automatically lead to `default` if there is no action specified.

Comment: I like an idea. Maybe you can rename to more suitable name, let's say `ApiPresenter`.